# VS2014 CTP 3 (VB.net) Experimental Language Features

Tags: visual-studio, roslyn

Is it possible to enable the experimental vb.net language features in the VS2014 CTP3 release, that where previewed in the VS2013 Preview?

To enable the C#6 language you can add the following to project settings.

```
<LangVersion>experimental</LangVersion>
```

Is there an equivalent for vb.net?

Comment: Strange question, you'd expect somebody to *first* ask what is still experimental.

Comment: J know what is experimental via the Roslyn CodePlex page.

Comment: No you don't, that was a fat year ago.  The point of VS2014 is to stop experimenting.  I only know of a C# feature that isn't yet frozen.

Comment: @HansPassant: http://source.roslyn.codeplex.com/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic/Parser/ParseExpression.vb,485

Comment: @HansPassant Language Feature Status Page https://roslyn.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Language%20Feature%20Status&referringTitle=Documentation

Answer (score 2):

```
<LangVersion>experimental</LangVersion>
```

It works for both VB and C#. Note that a features that's "experimental" in one language might not even be in the other language. Sometimes a feature is experimental enough that we don't even want to spend the effort to put it in both languages until we're reasonably confident it's a good feature.

*Note:* it turns out there's a bug in Visual Studio "14" CTP 3 that causes this flag to not get passed to the language services. It works fine if you build it with 'msbuild' on the command line.